# Java's g.drawImage takes significantly longer on Windows over Linux

Tags: java, linux, windows, swing, drawimage

For a class project I and a few others are working on an isometric game. Everything is being drawn in one JPanel using a buffered image. Each piece of artwork is done in fireworks and saved as a .png.

On Linux, the time it takes to redraw the map every game tick is around 3ms. On Windows (and also OSx) it's around 100ms spiking to 500ms.

This effect has been observed on 4 different computers ranging from typical laptop to an i7-3770K + 660 gaming machine. The CPU usage when this occurs is around 10-20% with RAM usage of the program being around 1GB. The problem has been researched on the internet in many places to no avail and also our section leaders (who are in charge of the project) were stumped. Any ideas?

Here is the paint component in the JPanel and the setEntityImage method. You can see where the time stamps are pulled from at the bottom of the paintComponent. The setEntityImage is being set every 500ms with a new BufferedImage that is pre-drawn on another thread before being passed into this JPanel. I'm including that code as I'm also curious if it's a possible threading issue.

This code is called every 500 ms to consist of a 'game tick', it draws the images (which are all pre-loaded in a static singleton class).

```
    BufferedImage entityImg = ImageUtil.getFromGraphics(map.getWidth() * TILE_WIDTH
            + TILE_WIDTH, map.getHeight() * TILE_HEIGHT + TILE_HEIGHT);

    Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D) entityImg.getGraphics();
    g2.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_ANTIALIASING,
            RenderingHints.VALUE_ANTIALIAS_ON);

    for (int i = 0; i < map.getHeight(); i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < map.getWidth(); j++)
        {
            try
            {
                int x, y;
                x = (j * TILE_WIDTH_HALF - i * TILE_WIDTH_HALF)
                        + map.getWidth() * TILE_WIDTH_HALF;
                y = j * TILE_HEIGHT_HALF + i * TILE_HEIGHT_HALF;

                Entity e = map.getTile(i, j).getEntity();

                if (e != null)
                {
                    g2.drawImage(e.getImage(), x, y, 32, 32, null);
                }
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
            }
        }
    }

    panel.setEntityImage(entityImg);
```

This code is in our MapPanel which extends a JPanel.

```
public void setEntityImage(BufferedImage entityImg)
{
    this.entityImg = entityImg;
}

@Override
public void paintComponent(Graphics g)
{
    super.paintComponent(g);

    Graphics g2 = (Graphics2D) g;

    g2.fillRect(0, 0, tileImg.getWidth(), tileImg.getHeight());

    // Draw tiles
    g2.drawImage(tileImg, 0, 0, null);

    // Draw box over square mouse is hovering over
    if (hover)
    {
        g2.setColor(new Color(255, 255, 255, 128));
        int screenX = (this.x * 16 - this.y * 16) + Window.WIDTH * 16;
        int screenY = (this.x * 8 + this.y * 8) + 16;

        g2.drawLine(screenX, screenY + 8, screenX + 16, screenY);
        g2.drawLine(screenX + 16, screenY, screenX + 32, screenY + 8);
        g2.drawLine(screenX, screenY + 8, screenX + 16, screenY + 16);
        g2.drawLine(screenX + 16, screenY + 16, screenX + 32, screenY + 8);
    }

    long time = System.currentTimeMillis();
    g2.drawImage(entityImg, 0, 0, null);
    System.out.println(System.currentTimeMillis() - time);
}
```

Comment: Make sure you're passing a `ImageObserver` through to `drawImage`, in this case the component should sufice, for example `g2.drawImage(entityImg, 0, 0, this);`

Comment: Also, timing `drawImage` is not a indication of the speed of the actual rendering process, as the `Graphics` context my still need to be pushed further up the rendering pipeline before been made available to graphics device.

Comment: *"I'm including that code as I'm also curious if it's a possible threading issue"* - Is possible, with no synchronisation around the creation, assignment and rendering of the `BufferedImage`, you could end up with possible dirty paints...

Comment: None of these seemed to have made a difference in rendering speed on windows.

Comment: Then were going to need an actual [runnable example that demonstrates your problem](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) to be able to state more...

Comment: Well, I struggled to parse out a very minimal code set for you, but hopefully this will help.

Classes you most likely will want to look at are:
Game - Has timer that notifies the Window
Window - holds the MapPanel
MapPanel - draws the map, this is where the lag is directly occuring


I would like to note that this code is for a school project, please don't steal. :) We're lowly young computer scientists.

http://people.oregonstate.edu/~woodti/RenderIssue/

Comment: Plz note, slight bug in that build, JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE is gone. Also click and drag to move the map around the screen.

Comment: Does it affect in any way if you set the affinity of the process to 1 core (Windows)?

Comment: Negative, no change in performance.

Comment: Do color models of image and of the screen device match? Are you using any `-Dsun.java2d.*` or `-Dswing.*` properties?

Comment: I removed the `for-loop` in `Window#tickUpdate` and got 0 millisecond updates.  This leads to think there is something going on with the entity images.

Answer (score 0):

There's some kind of internal optimisation caching going, the particulars I'm not aware of.  Essentially, if the `BufferedImage` is not updated, it paints in 0ms.

I did two optimizations, not sure if either work alone or not but it made a difference in the performance, but not in the time delay (ie, When I dragged the map about, it was significantly better)

The first was in `Window#tickUpdate`. Rather the creating a new `BufferedImage` every 500ms, this simply re-uses a single `BufferedImage` only creating a new instance if there wasn't a previous instance or the size has changed...

```
public void tickUpdate(Map map) {
    int width = map.getWidth() * TILE_WIDTH + TILE_WIDTH;
    int height = map.getHeight() * TILE_HEIGHT + TILE_HEIGHT;
    if (entityImg == null || entityImg.getWidth() != width || entityImg.getHeight() != height) {
        entityImg = ImageUtil.getFromGraphics(width, height);
    }

    Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D) entityImg.getGraphics();
    g2.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_ANTIALIASING,
            RenderingHints.VALUE_ANTIALIAS_ON);

    g2.setComposite(AlphaComposite.getInstance(AlphaComposite.CLEAR));
    g2.setBackground(new Color(255, 255, 255, 0));
    g2.clearRect(0, 0, width, height);
    g2.setComposite(AlphaComposite.getInstance(AlphaComposite.SRC_OVER));

    for (int i = 0; i < map.getHeight(); i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < map.getWidth(); j++) {

            Entity e = map.getTile(i, j).getEntity();

            if (e != null) {
                int x, y;
                x = (j * TILE_WIDTH_HALF - i * TILE_WIDTH_HALF)
                        + map.getWidth() * TILE_WIDTH_HALF;
                y = j * TILE_HEIGHT_HALF + i * TILE_HEIGHT_HALF;
                g2.drawImage(e.getImage(), x, y, 32, 32, null);
            }
        }
    }
    g2.dispose();

    panel.setEntityImage(entityImg);
    panel.repaint();
}
```

And because the `BufferedImage` could be updated while a paint was occurring, in the `MapPanel`, I created a another `BufferedImage` onto which the "entity" image was painted.

```
public void setEntityImage(BufferedImage img) {
    entityLock.lock();
    try {
        if (entityImg == null || entityImg.getWidth() != img.getWidth() || entityImg.getHeight() != img.getHeight()) {
            entityImg = new BufferedImage(img.getWidth(), img.getHeight(), BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB);
        }
        Graphics2D g2d = entityImg.createGraphics();
        g2d.drawImage(img, 0, 0, null);
        g2d.dispose();
    } finally {
        entityLock.unlock();
    }
}
```

`entitytLock` is just a `ReentrantLock` which I used to stop the `paintComponent` method from trying to paint the `BufferedImage` while it was been updated.

This doesn't change the timing, but made it, visually, better...

An alternative is to use a `VolatileImage`...

Comment: I will try this when I get home from class today, thank you for the help!

Comment: After I posted, I was reading a little deeper into the code and y appear to be using a null layout and placing the position of the panel based on the drag offset, this means you are painting the entire image of the entities each time, this may be cussing the slow down. A better solution would be to have a virtual concept of the world (so the panel was only ever the size of the window) and only render the portion of the view which is visible (may be using BufferedImage#subImage) you might find produces better results

Comment: It's not the offset, if I disable the notifyObserver in the game tick it's completely smooth dragging around the map, it's as soon as you draw a new BufferedImage and set it as the entityImg in the MapPanel

Comment: The panel is offset (using setLocation), but still the whole BufferedImage is painted. It might be better to swap the concept, keep the panel no larger then the window and only draw what's visible

Comment: I have done this, had no affect on performance. It has to be something different than just how much of the image is being drawn as it works perfectly on Linux.

Comment: It's the difference between how the BufferedImage is pushed the hardware, either directly or via the render pipeline. I believe that DirectX is used on windows and mac is natriously for not allowing access to the hardware layer. You could try disabling the DirectX rendering pipeline in favour of OpenGL

Comment: Couldn't figure this out still, program was due this week so we just made note to the grader and asked him to grade it on a Linux machine which was no problem. Strange bug, I might look into it more this summer as I'm still curious.